# What is Fusion in .NET Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

In Suzanne Cook's blog there is such a description:

> **LoadFrom Context:** In general, if the user provided **Fusion** a path which was used to find the assembly (and the assembly at that
>   path wouldn't have been found in the Load context), then it's in the
>   LoadFrom context. There are various methods to load by path:
>   LoadFrom(), CreateInstanceFrom(), ExecuteAssembly(), loading an
>   assembly through interop using a codebase, etc.

And also I found an MSDN article about it but I am not really sure whether the Fusion Suzanne talks about is same as here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx but it seems a Log viewer so what I understood what Suzanne says is

> **Fusion** is a probing mechanism which takes path, etc and it probes
>   assemblies in Application Base, `codeBase`, GAC, etc. to load them into the context.

Some one can clarify this please?

Comment: MSDN is lacking better documentation some of the time even though they provide one of the best documentation in the World.

Comment: Docs now at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fusion is the code name for the assembly loader in .NET. If memory serves, Suzanne was on the Fusion team and wrote much of the [Assembly binding log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You can see the hint of the codename in this program, as it's called `fuslogvw.exe`

It is fusion's job to seek out assemblies and load them into the current app domain so that a program can execute. The Assembly binding log viewer shows where it looks to find assemblies, and any issues that may arrise in loading them. Great for debugging.

Comment: Hanselman has a nice little summary of using Fusion.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Have you seen supporting Fusion documentation? Not how to enable or view the logs. That's well covered.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Fusion is the name for the 'subsystem' in .Net that provides the lookup mechanism for assembly resolution/loading.